# Couldn't find CustomXmlDataStoragePart! exiting.. error add XMLto Word with docx4j

Tags: java, docx4j

```
    public void xmlToWordExport() throws Exception {

    String input_DOCX = "D:/Temp/data_template/template.docx";      
    String input_XML =  "D:/eclipse/jaxb.xml";      
    String OUTPUT_DOCX = "D:/eclipse-workspace/PWCRAR/OUT_ContentControlsMergeXML.docx";    
    WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(new File(input_DOCX));
            CustomXmlDataStoragePart customXmlDataStoragePart 
                = CustomXmlDataStoragePartSelector.getCustomXmlDataStoragePart(wordMLPackage);
            if (customXmlDataStoragePart==null) {
                System.out.println("Couldn't find CustomXmlDataStoragePart! exiting..");
                return;         
            }
            System.out.println("Getting " + input_XML);


    FileInputStream xmlStream = new FileInputStream(new File(input_XML));



    Docx4J.bind(wordMLPackage, xmlStream, Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_INSERT_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_BIND_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_REMOVE_SDT);

    //Save the document 
    Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, new File(OUTPUT_DOCX), Docx4J.FLAG_NONE);
    System.out.println("Saved: " + OUTPUT_DOCX);
}
```

error:
org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Couldn't find CustomXmlDataStoragePart! exiting..

[xml click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSNtt.png)

Why couldn't find CustomXmlDataStoragePart? How to fix it?

Comment: You can turn logging on for https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/datastorage/CustomXmlDataStoragePartSelector.java for more info.  But I guess your template.docx is incorrect. How did you create it?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj889465.aspx  the way to create the template

Comment: Actually,I wonder is it possible that the data style of the xml is wrong

Answer (score 2):

CustomXmlDataStoragePartSelector is intended to work with documents using content controls according to the OpenDoPE spec: see http://www.opendope.org

The easiest way to set up your document is to use one of the Word AddIns, either http://www.opendope.org/downloads/authoring-friendly/setup.exe or the older/uglier http://www.opendope.org/downloads/authoring-advanced/setup.exe

See further http://www.opendope.org/implementations.html